# Difference between int(x) and mediumint(x) - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, types

Difference between TinyInt / SmallInt / MediumInt / Int / BigInt in MySQL data type ?
I want to use an [unsigned] integer field with 11 length, what should i use ?

*[I'm using PHPMyAdmin]*

Comment: Is there something specific the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) doesn't cover?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Type            Range
TINYINT         -128 to 127<br>
SMALLINT        -32768 to 32767<br>
MEDIUMINT       -8388608 to 8388607<br>
INT             -2147483648 to 2147483647<br>
BIGINT          -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
```

You should use `BIGINT`.

Comment: @Sourav, For Int(11), a normal int suffices.

Comment: @Johan, if he wants an integer with length 11 (99,999,999,999), wouldn't that be bigger than 2,147,483,647?

Answer (score 0):

Check the official documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html